# Mudar aparência da AlertDialog para a antiga

Tags: android

Tenho esse código que cria uma AlertDialog

```
public void mostrar_popup(){
    AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    dlg.setCancelable(false); //impede que a janela seja fechada ao clikcar fora
    dlg.setMessage("É preciso digitar um texto para continuar ");
    dlg.setNeutralButton("OK",null);
    dlg.setPositiveButton("sim",null);
    dlg.create();
    dlg.show();
}
```

E o resultado é esse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esse é o resultado que eu gostaria que saísse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode setar o tema por parâmetro no [`AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int themeResId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html), da seguinte maneira:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```

*Antes era usado o tema: `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`, de acordo com a nova documentação esse tema está obsoleto.

Caso queira dar uma olhada nos [temas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html) disponíveis.

Também é possível criar o seu prório tema customizado, conforme esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog).